# VS Code opens not logged in to any accounts

Tags: macos, authentication, visual-studio-code

I have recently installed vs code on a new iMac with Big Sur. VS Code 1.55 and I have settings sync and GitHub extensions that require a GitHub login. I am forced to re-login to GitHub via the profile button in the bottom left corner every time I restart VS code. On my Windows system the login persists through restart. How can I fix this on Mac OS Big Sur?

Answer (score 5):

Found out that if you open vs code after downloading from the downloads folder it messes up keychain access. Remove VS Code and download again, then move to applications folder before opening for the first time and the issue is resolved.

Comment: I can confirm that this worked for me too using MacOS Ventura.

Answer (score 0):

I was dealing with a similar issue, I was logging in every time I open the VSCode, moving VSCode from download folder to applications folder worked for me. (MacOS Ventura)