# VS Code needs to sign in after every restart

Tags: visual-studio-code

I got an pretty annoying issue, I recently updated to macos Ventura Beta. Since then I have to sign to my Github account on every restart of VS Code.

Anyone got this issue too?

Comment: The same happened to me, this fixed it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67172881/vs-code-opens-not-logged-in-to-any-accounts.